# Website inaccessible from Three Ireland

Tags: vpn, proxy, privacy, isp, blocking

I have a user who requires access to deviantart.com over a hutchinson (Three/Wampoa etc) mobile connection in Ireland.  The situation is the user can only access the site over proxy/vpn.

The problem isn't DNS.  DNS resolves and the user can ping the domain/servers without VPN/proxy.

Does anyone know if Three Ireland is censoring deviantart.com? 
If yes are how are they doing it and is there any remedy?
Is the user going to have to resign themselves to obfuscating their connection every time?

In passum: In the last year or so Three Ireland seems to have increased the number of censored domains.  For example most anonymizing proxies are now banned.

Answer (score 1):

#### Does anyone know if Three Ireland is censoring deviantart.com?

I don't know if deviantart.com is specifically blocked, however they do have Adult Content filtering on their mobile network.

The filters are **on by default**. You can ask to have it removed:

> **Removing mobile filters on the internet**
>
> Three have Internet filtering schemes to block certain content from
>   users. These filters are designed to protect minors from accessing
>   adult material. The filters are turned on by default when anybody
>   purchase a mobile.
>
> To verify your age you can either;
>
> - please use our Live Chat Service from 7am till midnight 7 days a week, or you should use the Contact Us Form where you’ll receive a
>     response within 4 working days.
> - walk in to a store with a valid ID proof to prove that you are above 18 years
>
> If you are a Prepay customer
>
> - You will also need to have registered your personal details with us – you can do this in the My Details section on My3, on the web at
>     www.three.ie/my3 or on your mobile in the bookmarks section of Planet
>     3.
> - Once you have done this, send us an email requesting that internet mobile filters are removed. We normally action this within 24 hours
>     and will send you a text message to confirm when we have done this.

Source [Removing mobile filters on the internet](http://ask3.three.ie/SRVS/CGI-BIN/WEBISAPI.DLL/,/?Command=New,Kb=ROIWebportal,Ts=ROIWeb,T=CaseDoc,Case=obj(10695))

Comment: AFAIK deviantart TOS forbids adult material. it seems ironic that it deviant seems to be blocked while tumbler, which according to google is at least 16% porn, is allowed.

Comment: @user3473715 No it doesn't. It blocks what it defines as obscene content but still allows [Mature Content](https://help.deviantart.com/220/). "Mature content on DeviantArt refers to deviations which contain content that may not be suitable for some audiences, such as nudity, excessive violence, blood, and other mature themes. Controversial pieces related to ideologically sensitive materials may also fall under these restrictions."

Comment: @user3473715 Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Apologies... for some reason I can't enter returns.... I must say I don't follow this argument at all.  To quote: "It blocks what it defines as obscene content but still allows Mature Content."  If I read this correct, tumblr is allowed because it is 'mature content' (presumably common or garden porn) but deviantart is blocked because, although it disallows 'adult' content in it's TOS, it serves some kind of content that is 'obscene' without being 'adult'.  Stimpy choking on a particularly difficult bit of powdered toast perhaps.

Comment: On rereading I understand the point made: I took the 'allows' to be concerning the filter action when it was meant to refer to DA TOS.

Comment: Yes. I wasn't commenting on tumbler or the three blocking just what deviantart allows.